# Accidently bought Deutschland ticket from Fahrplanner app one month earlier than required

Tags: germany

Due to the DB app requiring IBAN, I used the Fahrplanner app and bought DB Ticket. the problem is, I booked it one month earlier than I actually require it.

I have not used the ticket once nor coudl  I use it , since I can only go to Germany on January (as my visum starts only then).

Is it possible to have my ticket shifted or get a refund? Thank you.

Comment: I feel this belongs on travel, not expatriates.

Comment: This is a matter of contract law. Withdraw from the original contract (generally possible within the first 14 days). Then make a new contract with the correct date.